# adding multiple widgets to a scrollview

Tags: python-3.x, scrollview, kivy

I am trying to get a scrollable table of widgets. Each row has a different input (given here by TextInput) but I have many more rows (12) than I have screen space so I am putting it within a ScrollView.

The problem is with the code below I get the following error.

```
 kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x10e0abf30>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.floatlayout.FloatLayout object at 0x10e0abfa0>
```

My guess is because you can't add multiple widgets to a layout without giving them all unique ids? I'm stuck as to why `main.add_widget(row_layout)` does not allow you to iterate as many times as needed?

```
.kv

ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
        MyWidget:
```

My widget looks as follows:

```
within .py

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    col1 = TextInput()
    col2 = TextInput()
    col3 = TextInput()
    col4 = TextInput()
    col5 = TextInput()
    col6 = TextInput()
    col7 = TextInput()
    col8 = TextInput()
    cols = [col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8]

    row_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
    print("Constructing row...")
    for col in cols:
        print col
        row_layout.add_widget(col)

    print("Iterating through rows...")
    main = FloatLayout(orientation='vertical')
    for row in range(12):
        print("adding...",row)
        main.add_widget(row_layout)

    self.add_widget(main)
```

Answer (score 1):

After some further tinkering I worked it out. It seems you need to create a new instance for every row.

```
class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    layout = GridLayout(cols=1,orientation='vertical',size_hint_y=None)

    layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

    for row in range(24):
        col1 = TextInput()
        col2 = TextInput()
        col3 = TextInput()
        col4 = TextInput()
        col5 = TextInput()
        col6 = TextInput()
        col7 = TextInput()
        col8 = TextInput()
        cols = [col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8]
        row_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', width=800,height=40,size_hint=(None, None))

        for col in cols:
            row_layout.add_widget(col)

        layout.add_widget(row_layout)

    root = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False)
    root.add_widget(layout)
    self.add_widget(root)
```

The associated kivy entry is simply:

```
.kv
MyWidget:
```